# Actualizar datos en usuarios en linea sin que refresquen

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, next

Tengo un forntend en React y el back en Nodejs.

Lo que necesito es actualizar ciertos datos de perfil a los usuarios que se encuantran actualmente en linea, cuando desde un usuario admin por ejemplo realizo otra acciones las cuales repercuten en todos los usuarios.

El panorama seria algo asi

Supongamos que los usuarios tienen entre sus datos uno que es oro y xps

Usuarios en linea:

**usu1**

- oro: 3000
- xps: 55

**usu2**

- oro: 2000
- xps: 50

**admin**

- oro: 1000
- xps: 10

En algun momento admin realiza una entrega de premios la cual edita estos datos en la base de datos (MongoDB) a traves del back, quedando asi:

**usu1**

- oro: 2000
- xps: 70

**usu2**

- oro: 3000
- xps: 53

**admin**

- oro: 2000
- xps: 15

Pero no logro refrescar estos datos en react hasta hacer el logout y login asi trae los datos nuevos para usu1 y usu2, admin si lo puedo manejar ya que es quien realiza estos cambios.

Por dodnde puedo investigar ? soketio ? grafql ? (De googlear me salieron esas opciones.)

Obtener un feedback segun cambios en el backend, que se refleje en vivo

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona el sitio y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso tienes que utilizar [socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat), tienes que instalar y configurarlo tanto como en el lado del frontend como en el backend. Ya que el frontend (en tu caso react) debe de estar pendiente escuchando las peticiones que se haga del lado del backend para que pueda recibir la data.